# Can I create a dictionary from excel file (not CSV) in python3?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

I am still a very bad programmer, currently starting my project.  I have mostly Java experience, but need to switch to Python3 for my project now.

I want to use the excel data files I have and build a dictionary for each column, meaning the list of values it takes.

I have done similar stuff with CSV files using the pandas library in Python3.

As far as I can go I imported the file with pandas, how do I create it into a dictionary? Should I take care of categorical data first or can that be done in the dictionary?

```
import pandas as pd

d = pd.read_excel("file.xls")
```

Comment: If you've done it with a csv, you can do with excel, it's no different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already partway there. `read_excel` will give you a dictionary of DataFrames when you use `sheetname=None`, which you can then convert individually into dictionaries using the `to_dict` method:

```
import pandas as pd

frames = pd.read_excel('file.xls', sheetname=None)
dicts = [df.to_dict('list') for df in frames.values()]
```

Answer (score 2):

Each column is really a pandas Series, which [can be converted into a list](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tolist.html), which can be placed inside a dict as you can with any list.

```
def df_dict(df):
    dict = {}
    for col in df:
        dict[col] = df[col].unique().tolist() # unique method optional
    return dict

dict_d = df_dict(d)
```

Comment: `df.to_dict('list')` is a much more concise way of doing this, ignoring the uniqueness

Comment: Excellent, the method by @asongtoruin is the way to do it if uniqueness is not needed.